# Can this convert into Livewire component without Alpine Js or Simplify to livewire-component (Tags input)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I want to make a Laravel livewire component for Tags input. I found one on the internet but it is difficult to connect with the livewire component. This is for the product attribute add page. I have added different attributes with values. So I try to do using tag inputs like the Shopify website. Can this code convert to the livewire component without alpine js or can it simplify the alpine js part to be compatible with the livewire component?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHpIX.png)

```
    <div class="relative" @keydown.enter.prevent="addTag(textInput)">
        <input x-model="textInput" x-ref="textInput" @input="search($event.target.value)" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter some tags">

        <div :class="[open ? 'block' : 'hidden']">
            <div class="absolute left-0 z-40 w-full mt-2">
                <div class="py-1 text-sm bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded shadow-lg">
                    <a @click.prevent="addTag(textInput)"
                        class="block px-5 py-1 cursor-pointer hover:bg-indigo-600 hover:text-white">Add
                        tag "<span class="font-semibold" x-text="textInput"></span>"</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <template x-for="(tag, index) in tags">
            <div class="inline-flex items-center mt-2 mr-1 text-sm bg-indigo-100 rounded">
                <span class="max-w-xs ml-2 mr-1 leading-relaxed truncate" x-text="tag"></span>
                <button @click.prevent="removeTag(index)"
                    class="inline-block w-6 h-8 text-gray-500 align-middle hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none">
                    <svg class="w-6 h-6 mx-auto fill-current" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M15.78 14.36a1 1 0 0 1-1.42 1.42l-2.82-2.83-2.83 2.83a1 1 0 1 1-1.42-1.42l2.83-2.82L7.3 8.7a1 1 0 0 1 1.42-1.42l2.83 2.83 2.82-2.83a1 1 0 0 1 1.42 1.42l-2.83 2.83 2.83 2.82z" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div> 

<script>
    function tagSelect() {
        return {
            open: false,
            textInput: '',
            tags: [],
            init() {
                this.tags = JSON.parse(this.$el.parentNode.getAttribute('data-tags'));
            },
            addTag(tag) {
                tag = tag.trim()
                if (tag != "" && !this.hasTag(tag)) {
                    this.tags.push(tag)
                }
                this.clearSearch()
                this.$refs.textInput.focus()
                this.fireTagsUpdateEvent()
            },
            fireTagsUpdateEvent() {
                this.$el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tags-update', {
                    detail: {
                        tags: this.tags
                    },
                    bubbles: true,
                }));
            },
            hasTag(tag) {
                var tag = this.tags.find(e => {
                    return e.toLowerCase() === tag.toLowerCase()
                })
                return tag != undefined
            },
            removeTag(index) {
                this.tags.splice(index, 1)
                this.fireTagsUpdateEvent()
            },
            search(q) {
                if (q.includes(",")) {
                    q.split(",").forEach(function(val) {
                        this.addTag(val)
                    }, this)
                }
                this.toggleSearch()
            },
            clearSearch() {
                this.textInput = ''
                this.toggleSearch()
            },
            toggleSearch() {
                this.open = this.textInput != ''
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't convert the above code exactly the same as I wish. But I could make a tag input system using the livewire laravel component. I feel this code might help someone to make the tag inputs using livewire Laravel.

//Livewire Component (app/Http/Livewire/)

```
    public $attributeOne = [];
    public $attributeOneTag;
    public $attributeOneTags = [];
    public $attributeOneTagsMerge = [];
    public $attributeOneId;

public function attributeOne()
    {
        $attributeOneTag = trim(str_replace(' ', '', $this->attributeOneTag));

        if (in_array($this->attributeOneTag, $this->attributeOneTags) || $this->attributeOneTag === '') {
            $this->attributeOneTag = '';
            $this->attributeOneId = 'attributeOneId';
            $this->emit('tagfocus');
        } else {
            array_push($this->attributeOneTags, $attributeOneTag);
            $this->attributeOne = array_merge($this->attributeOneTagsMerge, array($this->attributeOneTags));
            $this->attributeOneTag = '';
            $this->attributeOneId = 'attributeOneId';
            $this->emit('tagfocus');
        }
    }
```

//livewire view component (resources/views/Livewire/)

```
<x-input.select wire:model='attributeOneTag' wire:keydown.enter='attributeOne'  :attribute="$attributeOne" :attributeId="$attributeOneId"/>
```

//Laravel Components (resources/views/components/input/select.blade.php)

```
@props([
    'error' => null,
    'attribute' => null,
    'attributeId' => null,
])

<input type="text" id="{{ $attributeId }}" class="form-control" {{ $attributes }}>

@isset($attribute)
    @foreach ($attribute as $item)
        @foreach ($item as $key => $value)
            <div class="inline-flex items-center mt-2 mr-1 text-sm bg-indigo-100 rounded">
                <span class="max-w-xs ml-2 mr-1 leading-relaxed truncate">{{ $value }}</span>
                <button wire:click.prevent='remove({{ $key }})'
                    class="inline-block w-6 h-8 text-gray-500 align-middle hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none">
                    <svg class="w-6 h-6 mx-auto fill-current" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M15.78 14.36a1 1 0 0 1-1.42 1.42l-2.82-2.83-2.83 2.83a1 1 0 1 1-1.42-1.42l2.83-2.82L7.3 8.7a1 1 0 0 1 1.42-1.42l2.83 2.83 2.82-2.83a1 1 0 0 1 1.42 1.42l-2.83 2.83 2.83 2.82z" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endisset
 
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', () => {
        window.livewire.on('tagfocus', inputname => {
            document.getElementById("{{ $attributeId }}").focus();
        })
    });
</script>
```